# Paths to bib-file on Win and OSX

Tags: bibtex, windows, mac, dropbox

I use Windows at home and OSX at the University. 
My tex files are synchronized via Dropbox. 
However, the path rules are, evidently, different in these systems.
As a result, I have to write something like this

```
\bibliography{D:/TeX/mybibfile}

\bibliography{/Users/df/TeX/mybibfile}
```

and comment/uncomment a line above depending on the operating system.

Does exist some more 'elegant/clever' way?

WBR,

Dmitri

Comment: Can't you just use relative paths? Or do you only synchronize the tex file but not the bib file with DropBox?

Comment: I synchronize bib file as well.

Comment: Well is it in the same folder? Then you don't need any path at all, only the filename. Otherwise use a relative path, that way you can copy the folder where ever you want and it works.

Comment: The elegant way is to set the `TEXINPUTS` accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

Use the `ifplatform` package and its `\if....` macros to test and define some command.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifplatform}


\newcommand{\DropboxPathPrefix}{%
  \ifmacosx%
  /users/def/TeX%
  \else%
  \ifwindows%
  D:/TeX%
  \else%
  \iflinux%
  .%   (local directory) Change to appropiate values
  \else% 
  \ifcygwin%
  % ????
  \fi%
  \fi%
  \fi%
  \fi%
}


\newcommand{\PathToBibFile}{\DropBoxPrefix/standardbiblio}

\begin{document}

%% Somes stuff in here


\cite{Lam94}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{\PathToBibFile}



\end{document}
```

(`standardbiblio.bib` is in fact the `biblio.bib` file from `texmf-dist/bibtex/bib/msc`)

[image]